# PHP reading live rss feeds, the fastest way

Tags: php, rss

I'm building a web-applIcation that reads from different sites the rss feeds. On every feed i can add a search key in the url, so the feeds are always different.

Now i'm using the simplexml_load_file, but this will take to long to read the feeds. Today i searched on stackoverflow and found the XMLReader class. This is a bit faster, but still not fast enough.

My question, is there a faster way to read multiple rss feeds that are always uniqe, so the user doesn't have to wait so long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke, i used different rss parsers like:
- SimplePie
- LastRSS

But the fastest way is to use the PHP XMLReader, because you don't have to read the whole xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [simplePie](http://simplepie.org/)  - the library is very easy to use, and implements caching that works well.

Another thing you can do to speed up perceptual load time is to load the page without the feed content, then pipe the feeds in with AJAX. If you stick a loader animation image in the content area where the feed will go and start the AJAX request on page load, the user will perceive that your page is loading faster - it will be usable faster, even if the feeds take the same total amount of time to load. Plus, users who are not there for the feeds can start doing what they need to do without waiting for content they don't even care about.

Comment: Thanks, but this reader isn't PHP 5 ready :( I see it is really fast!

Answer (score 0):

Why not cache 5 or 6 feeds in files that can just be included randomly when there is a user request.  That way the user does not end up waiting for a feed to be processed.  The cached files can be refreshed every 10 or 15 minutes with a cron job so there is always fresh content.

Comment: Not possible, because the feed has a search word in the url that is always different.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need to do is to read not the whole RSS Feed and parse it but to get only a part of it. If you use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents)() you can set a limit to not download the whole page but only the first part.

Of course your RSS Feed is broken then. I don't now how your reader reacts to this. Maybe you can let him ignore it or fix the broken feed end.

Here you go:

```
$feed = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/...', false, null, -1, 1000);
$end = strpos($feed, '</entry>', -1);
echo substr($feed, 0, $end). '</entry></feed>';
```

Comment: `file_get_contents` is probably the best way to read the data, but your suggestion to only read a portion of the document is not a good one. How would the developer know how much of the document to fetch so he isn't cutting off articles in the middle, or even cutting off a tag in the middle? Then you've got an invalid XML document that cannot be correctly parsed. Also, would it hurt to spell check?

Comment: Yes it sucks, but I is a very easy way to go here. That is why I am saying you have to fix the broken feed. You lose one feed entry, so what?

Comment: Sure you can use fopen/fread and parse the feed yourself but that is way more work.

Comment: How do you know you "lose one feed entry"? If you just throw some arbitrary `max_len` argument at `file_get_contents`, you don't know **what** you're going to get. Could be all but the last article, could be 1/3 of the first article. You would also have no easy means to "fix the broken feed" since you have no idea what you've cut out. You'd spend more execution time trying to figure out what the mess of broken XML needs to be "fixed" and valid than you would have if you had just retrieved the entire feed. You're better off not breaking it in the first place. -1

Comment: Thanks for the corrections! Fixing the broken XML is very easy. Just search for the last entry ending and cut of the rest (see above).

Comment: Parsing XML or HTML with string functions is bad practice on its own. Don't take this personally, but this whole answer really is all bad practice. First, you're breaking (presumably) valid XML unnecessarily, then you're using string functions to "fix" it? Why create a problem in the first place only to solve it with more problem-prone approaches? Both the "problem" and the "solution" here are avoidable by using good practices to start with. Really, with all due respect, this answer is the completely wrong approach.

Comment: So we agree it works but it's ugly. What else can we do? You can use caching but that gets you nothing if the feeds "are always uniqe" as OP said. We can search a proper parser that can handle the broken feed or we can write one. For both I don't have the time.

Comment: No, not "it works but it is ugly", but rather "this is bad practice, find a different way"